# emacs --no-window-system

Tags: emacs

So I've started emacs with

```
emacs -nw
```

And it looks the other way then the one I customized and start with

```
emacs &
```

How do I bring my settings to "emacs -nw" - and also how to work there? Arrow keys doesn't work - and so on. Also a menu - I can't use it - it as expected do not responce to mouse clicks. Do you have any docs about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about colorization and similar changes emacs is limited by the power of the terminal or terminal emulator you are using ***and*** by the terminal you *tell* emacs you are using.

Check your terminal setting with `printenv TERM`, and check the capabilities of your terminal emulator in it's documentation.

If you are using a xterm, consider setting `TERM=xterm`, which generally supports colorization and some font changing.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, only calls without "-nw" support mouse actions. I may be wrong because I have seen vim have some mouse support.

Arrow keys? I don't know why they dont work for you, so I support the answer asking that you check your TERM settings and add that a way out is to either try a different build of emacs, or forget your default terminal and fire up `xterm &` or `rxvt &` prior to any `emacs -nw` work.

To answer your question on menus... look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191312/how-do-i-get-to-the-menu-in-emacs-in-console-mode

You'll get a dynamic pop-up that simulates your having pressed the menu-summoning Alt key and doing a text-mode navigation. For example, *quitting emacs* is as easy (or hard) as hitting `F10` and pressing `f` and then `q`. The problem is that the default terminals on Macs, and Ubuntu 10.10 eat up that key press to trigger their own functionality, like the `gnome-terminal` menu or the MacOS `Dashboard`.

You have to turn off the feature depending on your OS or terminal's keybindings. Macs have a System Preference pane to do that, and gnome-terminal has preferences in the `Edit menu`. I don't remember if cygwin misbehaves and what the fix was, but I know it was working for me.

If you meant having a visible menu... it depends on your emacs version, whether you see one by default. On MacOS I don't, but on  Ubuntu it shows up by default without any .emacs file configuration. You probably can make it work permanently by editing (or creating) ~/.emacs and adding the line
`(menu-bar-mode t)` 
You can comment that out at any time by using the `;;` comment marker.
PS: You'll have the sad realization that this menu bar in your `no-window mode` is just a decorative gimmick, and does NOT take mouse input. So it's just there to show you indirectly the language mode it's using (by what menu headers change to as you switch from `.sh` files to `.cpp` and so forth)